# Unable to show data from ajax in HTML table

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I am making an ajax call on click of anchor tag : 
There i have a number of arrays as output . 
But i am unable to display those arrays in an HTML table . Please suggest how can i achieve this .

```
function getdetail(cid)
{
var cid = cid;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "c_detail.php";
var params = "cid="+cid;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {               
            document.getElementById('cdetail').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;        
        }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url+"?"+params,true);
xmlhttp.send();
 }

My array output looks like this : 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 5088 [start] => first [end] => last [ad_start] =>ad_first [ad_end] => ad_last [cid] => 79 [car] => Dialog ) )
```

Of-course this shows data as list of arrays without any formatting . I want to display it as HTML table 
Any help will be appreciated !!! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Need more info, a snippet of html to find out what type of element `#cdetail` is and some sample responseText to see what you're trying to display.

Comment: if you have server side access then change server side code to send data in html format the you want or create javascript function to format the array data.... and of course if you send unformatted data from server side and you just put the response in a div then it will display data as list of array

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can i format array data using java script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I advise you to use an existing library like [datatables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html), and you have to convert the php array to json data through `json_encode($array)` function.